# Remove the collation of a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, collation, alter-column

How can I remove the collation of a column after it has been set?

The standard collation of a column in the SQL Server is "NULL". It means, the collation of the database is used.

The TSQL-Statement `ALTER table ALTER column COLLATE database_default` will explicit set the collation of the column to the one of the database, but it doesn't restore the original state of no collation (NULL collation).

Can we really drop the collation?

Comment: So what's the difference between `NULL` meaning database default, and the `database_default` then??

Comment: The difference appears in queries of sys.columns and by changing the database collation itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't drop the collation of a column or even of a database.

1: If you do not specify any collation, the columns will use the **default collation** of the database.

2: If no collation is specified by the database, then the **server collation** is used.

Comment: Confirmed this, sort of sucks. HOWEVER if you use the designer in SQL Manager you can select the text column you want to reset, click the "..." button in the "Collation" property grid, in the popup window select "Restore Default". The SQL Manager will script all the DROP + CREATE commands to essentially reset it to the NULL state by recreating the column. IF that is acceptable to your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** restore the `COLLATION` of a `COLUMN` back to the database default; you simply use `database_default` as the collation name you want:

```sql
ALTER TABLE someTableName ALTER COLUMN someColumnName [nvarchar](255) COLLATE database_default`
```

I am using this simple script to generate all the SQL statements. I have seen other scripts that create the statements and execute them, but they were for specific named collations.

```sql
SELECT   TABLE_NAME,
         COLUMN_NAME, 
         COLLATION_NAME, 
         CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME ,' ALTER COLUMN ', COLUMN_NAME ,' [',DATA_TYPE,'](',CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH,') 
COLLATE  database_default') AS theScripts
FROM     information_schema.columns 
WHERE    COLLATION_NAME IS NOT NULL 
  AND    collation_name <> 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
  AND    data_type LIKE '%char%'
```

Comment: `ALTER table ALTER column COLLATE database_default` was specifically mentioned in the question and doesn't do what the question asker wants (though why they want that I have no idea)